# Spring Scheduling with calculated initialDelay

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, delay, scheduler

I am running a method in my application, with a fixed delay of a week. But I need the method to run for the first time only at 12 midnight on Sunday. I can get the date-time using the Calendar util, but how do I set that variable in to the initialDelay parameter?

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedDelay = 1000*60*60*24*7)
public void updateLeaderboard() {

    System.out.println("updating leaderboard");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a cron expression for that:

`0 0 0 * * sun`

or more specifically:

`@Scheduled(cron="0 0 0 * * sun")`